# selenium running web application on mobile version instead of desktop version

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having an issue when I try to run my selenium webdriver tests, they run ok locally but when I try to run them on a linux server, the web application runs on mobile version and I'm seeing that some elements are not visible running the tests so I need the desktop version(I'm taking screenshots on the server so that's how I found it's running the mobile version), I was reading about these kind of problems and seems this one has to do with browser size when the app first loads, I'm using chromedriver and this is the configuration I have:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',
        desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
    self.driver.set_window_size(1900, 1200)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
```

The 2 last lines maximize my screen on the screen locally but not sure what is doing on the server.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your site might be a responsive design which means that the design adapts to the size of the browser, e.g. desktop resolutions vs tablet vs mobile, etc. When you run the code above and take a screenshot, does it show as 1900x1200? If the server is set to a super low resolution, maximizing the browser probably reduces the resolution down from 1900x1200 which may be causing the issue. Take out the maximize command and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

thanks JeffC , I found the solution, instead of using :

```
self.driver.set_window_size(1900, 1200)
self.driver.maximize_window()
```

I'm using:

```
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
```

removing the maximize command helped me .